# How to set space between 2 views relative to screen width without using margin property in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I tried to set a space between two view (horizontal and vertical) like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.SetProfileFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Test 1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Test 2"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But I want the space between the two `TextViews` to be 1% percent of screen. Is it possible?

Comment: For that  you can add the margin at runtime...like you can find out the screen width and height at runtime and add the 1% of margin to your view

Comment: so I have to set margin programatically?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: thanks so much but it kinda complexity , i want to rexponsive layout, if i hard code space by margin, is it ok ?

Comment: Instead of margin you can use padding also...please check the below code i have added..

Comment: I think using `dp` should be fine as `dp` is based on the physical density of the screen... cmiiw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I want to spacing two TextView 1% percent of screen. is it possible?

- **For setting the start & top constraint to the parent:** Use [Horizontal & Vertical Guidelines](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Guideline) with percentages of the root `ConstraintLayout`:

  The 1% is considered as 0.01 as 1% equals to the full screen width >> So, use `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.01"`

  You can apply the constraints to the `textview1`, and in order not to repeat yourself, you can constraint `textView2` to the BaseLine of `textview1`.
- **For setting the 1% of the screen width between the TextViews:** Use Space that is constraint to the end of `textView1` with a percentage of 1% of the screen width: `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.01"`. Then constraint the `textView2` to the Space, not to `textView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.SetProfileFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.01" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.01" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test 1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline2" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.01" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test 2"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/space"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
    val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
    windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)

    val width = displayMetrics.widthPixels
    val height = displayMetrics.heightPixels
    val widthPer = (1*100)/width  //1% percentage width
    val heightPer = (1*100)/height //1% percentage height
    textView1.setPadding(widthPer, heightPer, widthPer, heightPer)  //Adding padding
    textView2.setPadding(widthPer, heightPer, widthPer, heightPer) //Adding padding
```